# disassembly of small hexa fragment in IDA pro

Tags: disassembly, ida

I want to disassembly small hex fragment, for example "6a2958996a"
in IDA pro in 64 bit mode?
Is there an easy way to do it?
Or i should create ELF file first and disassembly it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDA can also load 'flat' binary file.

Open an empty file with an hex editor and input the required bytes in it.

I prefer to go directly with python 3.x :

```
>>> with open("c:\\tmp\\tmp_file.bin", "wb") as f:
    f.write(bytearray.fromhex("6a2958996a"))
```

Open IDA (64-bit version) and open the binary file with it.

1. Keep the default options (or choose the right processor, e.g. '686p'):

[image]

2. Make sure you select 64-bit mode:

[image]

3. By default the code is not disassembled:

[image]

4. Put the cursor on the first byte (0x6a; address 0x00) and then press '**c**' to make it code rather than undefined byte:

[image]

Well, the example is not a completely valid code (0x6a is awaiting for another byte) but you get the whole idea...